# How to stop or exit from a running thread when some condition matches in python

Tags: python, multithreading

How to stop or exit from a running thread when some condition matches in python in the following code :

```
import threading

class RR_Client(client):
    def __init__(self,client_name):
        self.del_counter=0
        self.client_names()
    def client_names(self):
        #some code
        if (some condition):
            self.del_counter=self.del_counter+1
        if self.del_counter !=0:
            #how to exit thread and return to main before thread is 
            completed ?
        #some more code



def main():
    # some code
    t=threading.Thread(target=RR_Client, args=(client))
    t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How about `return` ?

Comment: That was my first attempt. Sadly it didn't work :-(

Comment: Are you sure your condition is met ?  Return should exit the function and terminate the thread.